# Forbidden AWS managed grafana /saml/acs url

Tags: grafana, saml, saml-2.0

In a project, I am using SAML authentication to connect AWS managed grafana to an Identity provider via keycloak as Identity broker.

While getting saml response back on `https://<some-grafana-url>/saml/acs` I am getting forbidden with error

```
{"message":"Failed to determine the state of the SSO redirect"}
```

I have checked NameIdPolicy Format in SAML Request is same as NameId Format under Subject in SAML response.
Certificate is also valid.

What else can lead to this error?